# Can I add @SuppressWarnings("*") on model class?

Tags: sonarqube

Can I add SuppressWarnings("*") on my model class? which I do not want Sonar to check my model packages.

@SuppressWarnings("*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube offers some easy to use configurations for that case.

For the easiest way it is important that you can easily determine either by a directory or by a folder. Than you can simply use `sonar.exclusions=`. Lets say your Model classes are suffixed with `Model.java` than you can easily use `sonar.exclusions=**/*Model.java` and none of them are analyzed. please see the [Sonar Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) for this.

If your Model classes do not share the same directory or naming convention, this approach is a lot of effort. But you can take a closer look, maybe you find a Pattern which you can use base on the [Sonar Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).

Additionally you have also the option to exclude files/folders based on the definition seperatly from coverage and from duplication analysis, if you still want to keep the issues.